# Installing "Restricted" drivers for turtlebot

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ubuntu, ubuntu-lucid, nvidia

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm unpacking and installing turtlebot I just received. The [setup tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/diamondback/Robot%20Setup) says:

```
DO NOT INSTALL THE NVIDIA RESTRICTED DRIVERS! Nvidia ION/Optimus is not supported yet in the nVidia restricted drivers.
```

On the other hand, Ubuntu Lucid shows an icon on the menu bar at the top of desktop, and clicking it shows a window that prompts installing "NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version current)".

So my question is whether I should install this driver as recommended by Ubuntu or not. I'm not yet getting if the 2 drivers above are the same or not.

We're thinking about utilizing ION graphics card.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10870/installing-%22restricted%22-drivers-for-turtlebot/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do not install the nvidia drivers, this will cause the display to crash and make the machine unusable.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-08-10**:
@mwise_wg Got it thanks!!!

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-08-10**:\

1. wait for NVIDIA to put a a working driver..(it's the best answer i have) 2) reinstall the turtlebot using the USB stick...

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-08-10**:
Questions remain (I'm not asking solution here) are 1) how to utilize ION board w/o NVIDIA drivers, 2) how to workaround the possible issues if I already installed it. I have multiple turtlebots and I've actually installed it on one of them already.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-08-10**:
@mwise_wg thanks. Then I assume that both drivers I mentioned are the same (or even any NVIDIA drivers should not be installed) and I avoid installing it.